# Local object creation in JAVA

Tags: java, object

I'm writing some JAVA assignment I got in school for a few days now, and I ran into something quite weird (well, at least for me it is...).
Since the question has nothing to do with my project in particular, I wrote some code that presents the behaviour I wanted to ask about, so please ignore any problems you might encounter in the following code, that don't relate to this specific issue.
Consider the following class:

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Car {

    List<Doors> doors;
    int numOfDoors;

    public Car(int numOfDoors) {
        this.numOfDoors=numOfDoors;
    }

    public void prepare() {
        run(doors);
    }

    public void run(List<Doors> listOfDoors) {
        listOfDoors=new ArrayList<Doors>(numOfDoors);
    }

    public List<Doors> getDoors() {
        return doors;
    }
}
```

And this:

```
package test;

import java.util.List;

public class TestDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Car car=new Car(5);
        car.prepare();
        List<Doors> listOfDoors=car.getDoors();

        if (listOfDoors==null) {
            System.out.println("This is not the desired behaviour.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("This is the desired behaviour.");
        }
    }
}
```

I agree, it's kinda stupid and has no point, but again - I wrote it only to satisfy my curiosity.

Now, as you might have guessed, the output is "This is not the desired behaviour.", meaning, the field "doors" holds a null pointer, even though it was assigned with a new object in "run()" method. so my question is why? why is it null?
I mean, I know that creating a local variable - may it be a primitive, an object or a reference to an object - will result in loosing it right when we leave the method's scope, but that is not exactly the case here, since there IS a **live** reference to that newly created object (doors), then why would JAVA destroy it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's analyse it step by step.

```
Car car=new Car(5);
car.prepare();
```

You create a new car, and you expect it to have a list of 5 doors, after the `prepare`.
Let's take a look now at what happens during `prepare`.

```
public void prepare() {
    run(doors);
}

public void run(List<Doors> listOfDoors) {
    listOfDoors=new ArrayList<Doors>(numOfDoors);
}
```

The `new ArrayList` is being assigned to the ***local variable*** `listOfDoors`.
When you write `run(doors)` you're not passing a *pointer to the variable `doors`*, as you might expect in a C context, for instance. You're passing a `null` (because `doors` insn't yet initialized) to the run method.

When *run* starts, we have

```
List<Doors> listOfDoors = null;
```

This is a result of passing the `null` reference upon invocation.
Then you assign a new list to this local variable, only to be destroyed when the method terminates.
As you can see, nothing was assigned to `doors`, leading to the unexpected behaviour.

To solve this, remove the *run* method and rewrite your *prepare* method.

```
public void prepare() {
    doors = new ArrayList<Doors>(numOfDoors);
}
```

With this, you should get the expected behaviour.

Comment: Ohh... OK, so basically this is the result of Java passing references **by value**...

Comment: @so.very.tired Exactly, the reference is passed by value. That is, the *address* that `doors` stores is copied and then passed, not the *address* to the `doors` variable itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things:

- passing parametrs as reference
- passing parametrs as value

In Java you can only pass parametrs as value - that means method `run` gets copy of `doors` reference (yes - it may be confusing). So now you have got `reference` `doors` and copy of this reference named - `listOfDoors`. But it refers to nothing yet. So when you write

```
listOfDors = new ArrayList<Doors>();
```

now `listOfDoors` references to arraylist of doors, but variable `doors` still reference to nothing.

So by the way - if you initialized your `doors` object before passing copy of that reference, you could write:

```
listOfDoors.add(new Door());
```

and it would be the same as

```
doors.add(new Door());
```

Despite those would be two different references, they would refer to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
public void run(List<Doors> listOfDoors) {
    listOfDoors = new ArrayList<Doors>(numOfDoors);
}
```

It should be:

```
public void run(List<Doors> listOfDoors) {
    doors = new ArrayList<Doors>(numOfDoors);
}
```

Read about [parameter passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference).

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `Doors` in `Car` constructor after checking the number of doors passed to the constructor.
Also, `run()` needs to access `this.doors` instead of accessing local doors (method argument).

Answer (score 0):

When you assign `listOfDoors=new ArrayList<Doors>(numOfDoors);` in run, you are not changing `doors`, because it is a different reference. Calling `run(doors)` creates a new reference to the object which `doors` refers to, which you are then setting and doing nothing with (this reference loses scope when `run` exits). The `doors` reference is never set to the object you're creating in `run`.

Answer (score 0):

The method `run` may have your existing `doors` as the parameter, but in the function the parameter `doors` gets overwritten with a new list (it is not the same object with a different content).

The original `doors` object therefore is still `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Java is not pass by reference.  so

```
public void run(List<Doors> listOfDoors) {
    listOfDoors=new ArrayList<Doors>(numOfDoors);
}
```

Does not update the same list that is passed in as the variable `doors` in `run(doors)`.  Instead the run method assigns to a new reference so your variable `doors` is never set.

This is also why the usual swap method does not work in java

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of assignment in the wrong direction, by passing door to `doors` to `run` you are having a new variable / reference which is declared as the argument of that method and which is local to that it, you then initialize it and it live only as long as the method executes. The variable `doors` remains unchanged. Its not like in `C` or `C++` where you can pass a pointer and assign a value to the object it is pointing to.

You need to initialize `doors`, a good place would be in the constructor:

```
public Car(int numOfDoors) {
    this.numOfDoors=numOfDoors;
    this.doors = new ArrayList<>(this.numOfDoors);
}
```

And there is no need - at least if you intention is that the method `run` works on the member variable `doors` - to pass a reference to it to that method, just write:

```
public void run() {
    // user this.doors here
}
```